# UIPrintInteractionController print last 3 images from photos app

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiprintinteractioncntrler

In my app I would like the user to tap a button to print the last three images in from the photos app (camera roll). I currently am using `UIPrintInteractionController` to print three UIImages from within the app using `printingitems`. How do I do this for the last three items from photos? Thank you.

```
@IBAction func print(sender: AnyObject) {

    var pic:UIPrintInteractionController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()!


    pic.delegate = self
    pic.showsPageRange = true
    pic.printingItems = [imageOne,imageTwo,imageThree]
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        pic.presentFromRect(self.printButton.frame, inView:self.view, animated:true, completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        pic.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: nil)
    }

}
```